# Get out of loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, html-table, break

I have such rows in my table in MySQL ( I wont post all the data which is in "table1", because I use only this) :

[image]

From this table I get each value with foreach loop and group it by "time_from" ascending order, because I need to start from the lowest one.

With echo I print such table in html :

[image]

I add the values to the table by checking the "time_from" database with those values that are printed with for loop. The problem is that when I don't know how to stop the loop at the exact time so it should start not from the beginning but rowwhere it stopped.

```
foreach ($mydbdata as $row) { //only as example,because I get all the data normally,checked everything with echo to get sure.
for($time = 0; $time <= 24; $time++)
{
    if($row['time_from'] == $time) {
         echo '<td>OK</td>';
    }
    else {'<td>BAD</td>';}
}
}
```

The problem is that it prints all the row, adds data corresponding to if clause, but when it goes to second check it prints again all the cells in the same row. I need somehow to stop the loop and get back,but start not from the start, but from that value on which it stopped. Any ideas how to do that? I have tried with "break;" but anyway, it is not starting from the place I need.

Comment: You can set the `$time` variable outside of the foreach loop and then in your for loop do something like `for($time; $time<=24; $time++){...`. That will not reset the value of `$time` on each iteration of the foreach back to 0.

Comment: if you want to start from the lowest value, you have to order ascending first. Because descending gives the highest value first.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, really I do it ascending. Need to edit.

Comment: You also need that `$` before `mydbdata` in the `foreach()`

Comment: RobP look at the comment. I wrote this only as example. Before for loop i get everything,just wrote as example. But i will edit to not confuse other users :)

Comment: You can create another column ex: recordSetId generate a unique id for a particular records sets and order descending recordSetId too and get only the rows relevant to recordSetId comes first, those are the last records sets you updated.

Comment: PHJCJO ID is already unique. I don't see the points for making a new column with new generated id.

Comment: Jonathan Kuhn it worked. It prints where it should be, but the problem is that it doesn't fill empty cells after the 2 iteration.

Comment: Found the solution. Had to play around with "break" usage. Also thanks Jonathan Kuhn.